# In Brain Creator, does unspent "atual" do anything?

Tags: brain-creator

[Brain Creator](https://www.kongregate.com/games/joao8991/braincreator) is an clicker-type incremental game on Kongregate.  When you ascend you gain "atual", but the rest of the game resets.

[image: Bran Creator screenshot]

**Question**: Does unspent "atual" do anything?

I've been spending atual on upgrades immediately, thinking it doesn't do anything if unspent.  But many incremental games grant an increase in production for unspent prestige points.

Comment: Just for future reference, you dont have to have a tag added in order to tag something. I dont have the rep (and dont even know how to) add new tags in, but it still let me submit "brain-creator" as the tag. :)

Comment: @KyleRone To clarify, you do have enough reputation to create new tags, and that is exactly how you do it.

Comment: Haha well now.. learn something new every day :p thanks buddy.